# Open Mac OS 9.1 and 9.2 image files with SheepShaver

Tags: macos, classic-mac-os

A friend from Greece has extracted the contents of Mac OS 9.x CD-ROMs and made them available to me:

- Mac OS 9.1 (Greek) as a non-bootable zip file (https://mega.nz/file/ykliWRZZ#blinsA6CxR5o_5vQ199VumkiREGWRWHCLIZ-_J8727Q)
- Mac OS 9.2.2 (Greek) as a bootable image file (https://mega.nz/file/XkVwlL4Z#lGCudujsL1kP2zu57QPOpUqatJlmGwwz2ZxTsTKS_Rc)

My questions are:

1. How can I make the first file bootable?
2. How can I open the second file in [SheepShaver](https://sheepshaver.cebix.net/)? SheepShaver complains that the ROM is not compatible (I downloaded it from https://www.redundantrobot.com/sheepshaver).

Comment: According to the feature list on SheepShaver's website (https://sheepshaver.cebix.net), SheepShaver "runs Mac OS 7.5.2 thru 9.0.4", that is, 9.2.2 is not supported.

Comment: An easier way to get macos 9 running might be to use UTM https://mac.getutm.app/gallery/mac-os-9-2-1